# Can't resolve 500 - Internal server error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, error, iis

I am running SharePoint Foundation 2010. I have 1 APP and 2 WFE server. I did setup (in IIS) bindings to a subdomain and IP. I have setup my application and it was working fine. I ran the SharePoint Search Server installation on all 3 servers and configured it. Now for some reason I am getting a 500 - internal server error and I can't find out why it is happening.

I have restarted IIS on all servers, checked log files, rebooted servers, made sure all services, app pools, and applications were running.

Any ideas?

Comment: check the event viewer, you should see something that gives you an idea! a 500 internal server error is usually not sharepoint but an iis problem.

Comment: check if you have conflict on the ports?

Comment: Whats the status of Central Administration?